# Teamcity - which external diff viewer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, diff, teamcity, external

Do You know any tools that can be used as external diff viewer for Teamcity's Visual Studio plugin?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Pro and Teamcity 5.1.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We use [Beyond Compare 3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) which is very easy to use with the TeamCity Plugin (set the path to the executable (BComp.exe) and set `%1 %2 /lefttitle="%3" /righttitle="%4"` as the Command Arguments.

A good open source alternative is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

Comment: thanks I'll check it out when im back at work (on vacation now)

Comment: You need quotes around the title values for it to work preperly: `%1 %2 /lefttitle="%3" /righttitle="%4"`

Answer (score 2):

With Beyond Compare 3, I use

```
%1 %2 /lefttitle="%3"  /righttitle="%4" /leftreadonly
```

The last option makes it so you can't accidentally edit base file

Answer (score 2):

For WinMerge (set path to WinMergeU.exe), I use the command arguments

```
/x /e /ub /wl /dl %6 /dr %7 %1 %2
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked at VS for a while, so I'm note sure what's changed in the last few years. That being said, I like a couple of Source Forge Projects in this area 
 [KDiff3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/) and
 **Notepad++** with the **Compare Plugin** from the plugins project.
and the reason I haven't paid a lot of attention to the Visual Studio side of things is that I am a Delphi freak, and the diff tool I've been using for years, because until recently even what I was using from Project JEDI's **JediVCS** which has an integral diff tool.

Comment: Other URL's would be http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/ and for the Delphi tool http://jedivcs.sourceforge.net/