# TeamCity Visual Studio plugin diff on double-click

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, teamcity-9.0

I am using the TeamCity plugin for Visual Studio 2015, and the Local Changes window is great for submitting private builds, easily assigning a check-in to a TFS task etc.

However, as my company is currently using TFS source control, the unified diff pane does not work ('Unified Diff is not supported by TFS integration'), so I would like to easily diff each file by double-clicking it rather than having to right-click each one and select 'Diff against workspace'.

Does anyone know how/if this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be achieved. There is no such related settings with TeamCity Visual Studio plugin. You can try to use external diff viewer such as **beyond compare**, more details please refer [Teamcity - which external diff viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546494/teamcity-which-external-diff-viewer)

Comment: I'm already using WinMerge which works fine with TeamCity. Perhaps JetBrains might add the feature in the future...