# Svn error when using external diff tool in TeamCity VS Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, svn, teamcity

I'm trying to use an external diff tool with TeamCity Plugin (2017.1.3) in Visual Studio 2017.

I have set it up to use WinMerge as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546494/teamcity-which-external-diff-viewer). When I click "Test" in the Options dialog, everything works nicely.

As soon as I try to select "Diff against Workspace" in the "Local Changes - TeamCity" panel, I get the following error message:

> svn: E200009: Destination file
>   'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpCCDF.tmp' exists, and will
>   not be overwritten unless forced.
>
> Svn has exited with code '1'.
>
> SvnExportCommand failed

I have also tried other diff tools, but the error remained the same. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any resolution to this?